# JSF redirect static resources to external host

Tags: jsf, resources, jsf-2

I'm running jsf app on glassfish v3. Machine has poor internet connection, so my idea was to move static content (css files, web graphics, fonts etc) to external hosting (using apache). I use jsf 2.0 resources, so links are generated like `/javax.faces.resource/screen.css.html?ln=css`. Question is, how can I automagically redirect such resources to external machine? The ideal way would be change it in one place (maybe glassfish configuration?) rather than change every link in whole app. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible with standard `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:outputScript>` components as the resources are loaded straight from the webapp context (and the classpath). Just use plain vanilla `<link rel="stylesheet" />` and `<script></script>` tags.

There was ever a spec change request for this: [issue 598](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-598). While this is targeted on JSF 2.2, I don't think that this will be implemented seeing the low votes.

Comment: But it's not the matter of scripts and styles only. I'm thinking of low-level approach eg filter for `/javax.faces.resource/*` that will strip everything but `screen.css` and send 301 redirect to `static-host.com/screen.css`. Is it good idea?

Comment: Hmm, this defeats the purpose of CDNs. You still keep receiving requests on those resources. One of the main points of a CDN is to minimize HTTP connections to your server.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. But content will be downloaded from static-host, so page will load faster. Would 301 responses have big impact on server performance?

Comment: Not the server performance, but more the client performance. A standard browser has a maximum amount of allowable connections on a specific domain (that's also why CDNs exist and/or some sites have static resources on a different domain). You could give it a try and measure. I've never done it like that. I only wouldn't be surprised if the browser possibly still accounts the redirected CDN request as one of the connections on the main domain.

Comment: OK, I'll have to test it. Thanks.